# icon in application manager on android not changing from default in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I'm building a android phonegap app. and all the icons are appearing fine, but i'm noticing the old default phonegap icon is still showing in the application manager list for the app. I deleted the default icon and removed the default entry from config.xml but its still showing up. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are refering to local deployments (eg. through the usb cable) and you have placed your icon.png files in the following locations:

```
 - <cordova-app-folder>/platforms/android/res/drawable-ldpi/ -- (36px x
   36px) 
 - <cordova-app-folder>/platforms/android/res/drawable-mdpi/  -- (48px
   x 48px) 
 - <cordova-app-folder>/platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi/ 
--  (72px x 72px)
 - <cordova-app-folder>/platforms/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/ -- (96px x
   96px)
```

I can only imagine that this is due to the fact that the device's application manager (within settings app) has temporarily cached the app icon, even when the application is uninstalled and reinstalled.  This can be easily resolved by restarting the device's settings application.

This is at least the case on a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 with the latest version of Cordova (3.3.1-0.3.1).

Comment: Excellent. I uninstalled the app and powered off. Turned it back on, installed and checked Application Manager - the icon is correct.